# Вопрос про неизменяемость поля first (key) в стандартных контейнерах типа Отображение

Tags: c++, map

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, что стандартные контейнеры `C++` типа `Отображение` хранят внутри себя пары, поле `first` которых является `const`? Или же внутри контейнеров хранятся пары с изменяемым полем `first`, но пользователь видит это поле (например - через итераторы) со спецификатором `const` при помощи какой-то хитрой магии?

Я спрашиваю, потому что решаю задачу написания отображения, которое вместо динамической аллокации элементов использует пул заранее созданных (пустых) объектов. И я столкнулся с нюансом: отображение должно быть в состоянии менять поле `first`, но пользователь должен видеть соответствующее поле со спецификатором `const`.

Единственная *законная* идея, которая пришла мне на ум, - это использование прокси-обертки. Такой подход имеет ряд минусов.

Использует ли стандартная библиотека такой же подход или же какую-то магию, - я понять не смог, исходники `STL` находятся за пределами моего понимания.

Comment: "*отображение должно быть в состоянии менять поле first*" - т.е. у вас контейнер может нарушать инвариант отсортированности по ключу? И вообще, я кладу в отображение что-то типа (1,"first"), а оно самопроизвольно превращается в (2,"first")?...

Comment: Нет, не так. Отображение должно быть в состоянии брать узел (с парой) из пула (списка), менять ему поле `first` и вставлять в нужное место.

Comment: Не понимаю. Какое, грубо говоря, оно имеет право менять ключ, который я ему дал?... :(

Comment: Оно его и не меняет, оно его копирует в соответствующее поле вновь взятого из пула элемента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начинка `std::map` зависит от реализации. Но раз из нее можно достать ссылку на `std::pair<const A, B>` и не нарушить strict aliasing, то внутри она скорее всего будет хранить тот же тип, с константным ключом.

> отображение должно быть в состоянии менять поле `first`

Есть вариант вызывать деструктор ключа (или всей пары), а затем конструктор ключа с помощью placement-new. Получившиеся пары перед использованием пропускать через `std::launder`.

Не уверен точно, но кажется, начиная с С++20 `launder` не обязателен, если сам пересоздаваемый объект неконстантный (даже если у него есть константные поля).

Comment: Да, я рассматриваю такой вариант, но мне кажется, что для решаемой задачи будет проще и надежнее реализовать резервируемое отображение без поддержки итераторов вовсе.

Comment: Изменение ключа может нарушить сортировку, что приведет к непредсказуемым последствиям.

Comment: @Croessmah Вопрос был не про это (не про изменение ключей в `std::map`), а про написание кастомной мапы. Которая использует пул пар, и должна мочь переиспользовать хранящиеся в нем пары.